# Is it possible to use a hexadecimal stored in a dword with getasynckeystate?

Tags: c++

Sorry if the title is kind of confusing but I am trying to use a DWORD with a value of 12, and use that with GetAsyncKeyState.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int x, y;
void click();
DWORD keybind = 12;

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(keybind))
        {
            Sleep(100); 
            click(); 
            Sleep(100); 
        }
    }
}
void click()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0); 
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0); 
}
```

I am probably trying to do the impossible here as I am new to coding but hopefully you guys can guide me in the right direction :) Also, the purpose of storing it in a DWORD and not just doing `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)` is because I wan't to grab the hexadecimal keycode from a txt file.

Comment: Change `DWORD keybind = 12;` to `DWORD keybind = 0x12;`  `12` is the decimal number 12; `0x12` is the hex humber 12 decimal number 18.  `VK_MENU` is defined as `0x12`.

Comment: A `DWORD` stores a binary value, not hex. Hexadecimal and decimal are formats for humans, because binary is rather verbose for humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a variable to `GetAsyncKeyState()` (though it takes an `int` as input, not a `DWORD` aka `unsigned long`).

Also, note that `VK_MENU` is HEX `0x12`. DECIMAL 12, as is being used in your code, is HEX `0x0C` aka `VK_CLEAR`.  So, change this:

```
DWORD keybind = 12;
```

To this instead:

```
DWORD keybind = 0x12;
```